# Run more than 1 process in Process Class

Tags: c#

Well, it will be a bit hard to explain what i need to do here, but it goes like this:

I am building a program that will need to run `.exe` (From different folders).

How can i do this, that i will be able to do `Process.start()`, but i will be able to kill it as well?

I mean, if I do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process;
process = process.start();
```

Then I can do `Process.Kill();` but what if I dont know how many processes I have? How can I do more and more processes with the ability to kill them?

Is this even possible?

I am hoping i explained it correctly. I am not sure how I can explain it better :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the created processes in a list to track them. Remove them from the list when you kill them:

```
var list = new List<Process>();

var p1 = Process.Start(...);
list.Add(p1);
// similarly for other processes, or run this in a loop

// later...
var p = list[0];
p.Kill();
list.Remove(p);
// ...
```

You can also use other specialized collections (like a queue) if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thats nice. how do i do that ?:O

Comment: I've put some sample code. But it's hard to know how to code should look like without more information.

Comment: When you do p1.kill, how will it know what to kill?.. and can you add alot of process with the same "P1?"

Comment: More info? well, i am going to run exe of a game.it will be about 10 process. so i will need to kill process5, or 4... and so on.

Comment: What's the logic to kill a process? When do you kill it?

Comment: I will kill it when i dont need the server runing any more. each process is a server.i will need to kill it :O.

Comment: And how do you know you don't need it anymore?

Comment: i will click a button to kill the process.

Comment: The idea of the list is to keep the references around. You should store it as a field in a class and then be able to reference its contents when you click the button.